# 20.04 Failed to Start Network error | fresh install

Tags: 20.04, network-manager, systemd, cockpit

In short there is an issue with the `network-online.target` that seems to propagate an error with that can be seen on my Cockpit dashboard as well as during boot screen.

Attached is an screen shot of the issue, I am fairly new to server administration with Linux.

Thank you all very much for the help!

---

Cockpit Dashboard - wait for network to be configured:

[image: cockpit dashboard - wait for network to be configured]

Cockpit Update Error:

[image: cockpit update error]

Comment: Found an fix, Ubuntu was trying to configure an non-bridged / connected network interface. Here is the link to my resolution: https://allones.de/2018/10/11/linux-a-start-job-is-running-for-wait-for-network-to-be-configured/